# Delete Firestore database from project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase project and I added a Firestore database but I forgot to choose the right location. Since the location can not be modified after creating the database and the database is empty I would like to just delete it and create a new one with the correct location. Is this possible or do I need to create the whole project again?

Would appreciate help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a region is set for a project, it can't be changed.  In the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#default-cloud-location) it says:

> Warning: Setting the location for one of the following services [Firestore, Storage, App Engine] also sets the location for the others. **After you set your project's default GCP resource location, you cannot change it.**

So, you will have to create a whole new project.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is no longer correct.  You can now delete the default database created `(default)` as well as creating other ones than the default, in other regions too.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-databases

I've just been able to do this on a test project, with the simplest firebase CLI command,

```
firebase firestore:databases:delete "(default)"
```